# Sort alphabetically and group by first letter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently doing a dictionnay, glossary here http://beta.emangaka.com/definitions

I sort the definition alphabetically.

definitions_controller.rb :

```
  def index
    @definitions = Definition.all.order('title ASC')
    @titre = "Définitions"
  end
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @definitions.each do |definition| %>
...
```

The list is too long and I'm looking for group by letter too always based on the first letter of "title".

How to do ? Merci. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`group_by`**](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by) like below

```
@definitions = Definition.all.order('title ASC').group_by{|d| d.title[0]}
```

And in the view

```
<% @definitions.each do |letter, definition| %>
  <h2><%= letter %></h2>
  <% definition.each do |defn| %>
    <%= defn %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ok thank you for that. I forgot to mention that as the list will be very long, it will be very long to unroll, scroll. I would create a clickable index by displaying only one letter group at a time and "All" (all show button).